# Is it possible to prevent the opportunity approval process from changing the close date to submission/approval date?

Tags: approval-process

Salesforce automatically switches the close date for opportunities from what value was upon user submission to the current date.

Is it possible to have a trigger that keeps the value of the close date the user had upon submission without changing it to the current date?

Comment: Mike -- There's not enough detail here to know exactly what you are doing but this Help article : http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004430&language=en_US may be your issue and includes a workaround using workflows